# Decrypting a GPG string from command line

Tags: c#, gnupg

I'm trying to write a console application that will decrypt a gpg signature on request. Everything's going fine, EXCEPT for the part where it prompts for my GPG password. How do I call `gpg --decrypt` from the command line without a password dialog?

Here's my code so far:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("gpg.exe");
startInfo.Arguments = "--decrypt"; //this is where I want to insert "--passphrase MyFakePassword"
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG";

var proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
var sCommandLine = stringData + "\n"+(char)26+"\n"; //stringData is the encrypted string
proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(sCommandLine); 
proc.StandardInput.Flush();
proc.StandardInput.Close();

var result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

I've tried using `--passphrase MyFakePassword`, `--passphrase-fd MyFakePassword` and even `--passphrase-fd 0` with my password on the first line of input. I'd like to avoid putting my password in a txt file on the machine that's running this code, if at all possible.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a bit more digging. A few months ago someone reported this as a bug on Gpg4Win's forums. The only solutions at this time are to roll back from 2.1.0 to a previous version (not an option in my case), disable the password for the key, or pipe it in from text. Here's the forum post: http://wald.intevation.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=1116&forum_id=21&group_id=11 There is no comment from the development team.

Comment: Thanks for this! Wasted days on it.Downloading ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/binary/gnupg-w32cli-1.4.9.exe and installing it fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 3):

Use the `--batch --passphrase-fd` options together, .eg `gpg2 --batch --passphrase-fd 0 --armor --decrypt /path/to/encrypted_file.pgp`

In your code, after `proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(sCommandLine);` add this:

```
proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("your passphrase here");
proc.StandardInput.Flush();
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the dialog password try this method, I use it and it worked perfectly, you will find more details.

http://www.systemdeveloper.info/2013/11/decrypt-files-encrypted-with-gnupg-from.html

```
    public static string DecryptFile(string encryptedFilePath)
    {
        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(encryptedFilePath);
        string decryptedFileName = info.FullName.Substring(0, info.FullName.LastIndexOf('.')) + "Dec.TXT";
        string encryptedFileName = info.FullName;

        string password = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["passphrase"].ToString();

        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");

        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
        psi.WorkingDirectory = @System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WorkingDirectory"].ToString();

        System.Diagnostics.Process process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
        string sCommandLine = @"echo " + password + "|gpg.exe --passphrase-fd 0 --batch --verbose --yes --output " + decryptedFileName + @" --decrypt " + encryptedFileName;

        process.StandardInput.WriteLine(sCommandLine);
        process.StandardInput.Flush();
        process.StandardInput.Close();
        process.WaitForExit();
        //string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        //string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        process.Close();
        return decryptedFileName;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Note: Doing this is a Security Risk!**

*Anyway,*

> passphrase when signing or decrypting unless you are using symmetric
>   encryption.
>   The man page documents the following options:

> **--passphrase string**

Use string as the passphrase. This can only be used if only one passphrase is supplied. Obviously, this is of very questionable security on a multi-user system. Don't use
this option if you can avoid it.

> --passphrase-fd n

Read the passphrase from file descriptor n. Only the first line will be read from file descriptor n. If you use 0 for the passphrase will be read from stdin. This can only be
used if only one passphrase is supplied.

```
--passphrase-file file
```

Read the passphrase from file file. Only the first line will be read from file file. This can only be used if only one passphrase is supplied. Obviously, a passphrase stored
in a file is of questionable security if other users can read this file. Don't use this option if you can avoid it.

The official pgp command line utility offers this capability with the -z flag:

> pgp -esa $SOURCEFILE $RECIPIENTPUBLICKEY -u $SENDERPRIVATEKEY -z
>   $PASSPHRASE

Comment: This is all correct information, straight from the documentation. I guess I should have been more clear that I've read the documentation, but the prescribed solution, `--passphrase "MyFakePassword"`, doesn't work. The reason for that can be found in my answer.